# how to download files from the path folder server local. NOT URL

Tags: python

**my_python.py**

```
import urllib2   
filedata = urllib2.urlopen('D:/python/uploadRM/app/file/myfile.pdf') #from local directory not url
datatowrite = filedata.read()
```

Comment: Please don't add random tags to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use with open() to read files from your computer

```
with open("D:/python/uploadRM/app/file/myfile.pdf") as myFile: 
    #rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to open a local file with `urlopen()`, but you could try using the `file://` HTTP scheme:

```
import urllib2

filedata = urllib2.urlopen('file:///D:/python/uploadRM/app/file/myfile.pdf')
datatowrite = filedata.read()
```

Generally you'd be better off using `open()` to open it as a normal file:

```
with open('D:/python/uploadRM/app/file/myfile.pdf') as f:
    datatowrite = f.read()
```